# Print first column of a file and the substraction of two columns plus a number changing the separator

Tags: awk

I am trying to print the first column of this file as well as the substraction between the fifth and fourth columns plus 1. In addition, I want to change the separator from a space to a tab.

This is the file:

```
A gene . 200 500 y
H gene . 1000 2000 j
T exon 1 550 650 m
U intron . 300 400 o
```

My expected output is:

```
A    301
H    1001
T    101
U    101
```

I´ve tried:

```
 awk '{print $1'\t'$5-$4+1}' myFile
```

But my output is not tab separated, in fact, columns are not even separated by spaces.

I also tried:

```
awk OFS='\t' '{print $1 $5-$4+1}' myFile
```

But then I get a syntax error

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written with shown samples.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1,(($5-$4)+1)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Why your output is not tab separated because you haven't used `,`(comma) to print separator hence it will print them like `A301` and so on. Also in case you want to set `OFS` in variable level in `awk` then you should use `awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1,(($5-$4)+1)}' Input_file` where `-v` is important to let awk know that you are defining variable's value as TAB here. Also I have used parenthesis with subtraction and addition to make it clearer.